# Post a link to a Facebook page as a page using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

When I use the field message and put in it the link it will be posted as a link string only without the pictures in the link as you post it from outside the graph explorer and the poster will be the name of the page via the application.

But when I use the `link` field and put the link in it, it will give the form that I want but the poster will be the name of the account and not the name of the page.

1st of all: i am trying the post in the graph API explorer before I use my C# console application that will post to the page wall. If I copy the link of a website page and open the page through Facebook and paste the link in the status filed it will automatically generate something like a form that contain the picture and some details and if I click post the status will appear as posted by the page itself and it will contain first the link as a text and then the form that I talked about will appear.

If I use the C# SDK and post the status as:

```cs
fbArgs["message"] = txtT.ToString();
facebook.Post("/PAGE_ID/feed", fbArgs);
```

the post will contain the link only without the form that appears automatically when I post the same string in the Facebook page website. If I use the `link` field with the link as a value it will be posted by the name of the account but with the form that I want?

How can I post a link that will generate automatically the form that will be created when you paste a link in the status edit box on the Facebook website?

Comment: Please, learn to use punctuation.

Comment: yes i promise i will but after i got the answer because i was so tired in searching for a solution and till now didn't get a one so i need the help plz

Comment: and there is a way that work on the api explorer but doesn't work in the c#
if i use the `picture` field it won't be posted without a `message` and when i use the `message` it won't post the pic!!!!

Comment: i need an answer plz @Hristo
do u know who can help me plz

Comment: No, I don't know the answer to your question. I've just edited its formatting and spelling.

Comment: should the question take more than 2 days to be answered?
because i need urgent solution